# How to store user meta data when using GKPlayer / Gamekit

Tags: iphone, ios, gamekit

I'm currently writing a turn based card game that will use Gamekit for multiplayer. It will also have a single player mode with AI. I'd like to store some user meta data (how many matches won, credits earned, etc). I'd also like to be able to display some match specific data about your opponent (credits earned in that game). What's the best way to store the local player's meta data as well as display opponent meta data? Would I subclass GKPlayer or connect the two in any way?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store data associated with a particular user, you could just use the `player.playerID` on the `GKPlayer`. No need to subclass at all, since you can just use that `playerID` as the key for any data you store.

For information about the other players, you might have to send that data over to the other devices using the Turn Based API.